# How to skip useless nodes for parser rule

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have a simple Antlr4 grammar:

```
grammar: test;
expression: 
    IF LPAREN logical ',' otherrule',' otherrule RPAREN # myExpression

logical:
        ......;
otherrule:
        ......;
IF: 'if'; 
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')->channel(HIDDEN);
```

When I use this grammer to parse:

```
 if(a>b, 1, 2)
```

the instance MyExpressionContext will have 8 children:

```
1 if
2 (
3 a>b
4 ,
5 1
6 ,
7 2
8 )
```

But I don't need ( ) and , those kind of separators, how can I make the children only have these?

```
1 if
2 a>b
3 1
4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the tokens by pushing them to `->channel(HIDDEN)`, just like you do with white space. I understand your problem though: sometimes you don't want to hide them, and then they are gone already.

Personally I think the benefits of getting them removed from your context will never outweigh the costs of the extra work and maintenance you have to do to workaround this. I would say: just accept the fact that there are tokens you will never end up using in your code.

Comment: Nice explanation! Thank you , Patrick!  It seems no way to remove them selectively. I ll just leave them un-removed and let own logic to deal with them.